# Accessing object item c#

Tags: c#, object

I have an object passed into a function. Now I want to access the object item like we have in the class function (EX: obj a: a.name):

[image]

I want to access level obejct slaType item.
"level.slaType"

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not passing the actual type?

Comment: Do you understand that the problem stems from the fact that your method signature isn't `public string callback(int x, int y, RealType level, string cellcontents = "")`, where `RealType` is the type of `level`?

Comment: Yes, Ronald there is reason behind it!! Actually the "RealType" will come from different class. so it should the dynamic!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast level object to that particular class type..

```
LevelType levelObject = level as LevelType;
if(levelObject != null)
{
    levelObject.slaType;  
}
```